# How can I apply a function to multiple columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, apply

If I have this data frame:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | word[ | another[ | third[ |
| 1 | some[ | one[ | four[ |
| 2 | this[ | two[ | five[ |

And I want to grab the word before the `[`  in each column and replace the original value with it.

I can do it column by column by doing something like this:

```
df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x: re.findall("([\w\s]*)\[", x)[0] if '[' in x else x)
```

But I would like to be able to apply it to all columns simultaneously.

I have tried:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: re.findall("([\w\s]*)\[", x)[0] if '[' in x else x)
```

But nothing happens. I'm sure I am missing some interaction with series and dataframes, since the method that works above converts the df to a series, while the code I tried that doesn't work keeps it as a dataframe.

This is what I am expecting to get:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | word | another | third |
| 1 | some | one | four |
| 2 | this | two | five |

Comment: there's no `[` in your input df

Comment: The question is a duplicate as asked, but actually, for this case, you might get better performance with Pandas' vectorized methods, though it's a lot more verbose: `df.apply(lambda col: col.mask(col.str.contains('[', regex=False), col.str.extract(r"([\w\s]*)\[", expand=False)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to accomplish that.

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract("(\w+)\[", expand=False))
print(df)
```

Here is another approach [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75892397/#comment133865008_75892397) by @[wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea)

> ```py
> df.apply(lambda col: col.mask(col.str.contains('[', regex=False), col.str.extract(r"([\w\s]*)\[", expand=False)))
> ```

---

```
      A        B      C
0  word  another  third
1  some      one   four
2  this      two   five
```

Comment: Why did you change the regex?

Comment: This doesn't account for the `if '[' in x else x` part, though OP's data doesn't have an `x` like that. You could use `Series.mask` to fix it; I posted a comment with that code.

Comment: @wjandrea I changed the pattern because I found it much simpler since it matches the string. You might be right if OP happens to have a larger df with change of string structure. I will include your suggestion in the answer.